# Problem in dynamically load data to Drop-Down list box in InfoPath 2007?

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

I have a Drop-Down list in my InfoPath form and I am loading some other fields based on the selection of the drop-down list. so that I have written code as follows for the "changed" event of the drop down list.

```
public void ProjectName_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
{
            string projectId = e.NewValue;
            dataQueryConnection = (AdoQueryConnection)this.DataConnections["ProjectInformation"];
            dataQueryConnection.Command = dataQueryConnection.Command + string.Format(" WHERE ProjectId = '{0}'",             projectId);
            dataQueryConnection.Execute();

}
```

For the first time when I change an item in the drop down list its working fine but for the subsequent changes of items(2nd time, etc..) its give the following error,

> The query cannot be run for the
>   following DataObject:
>   ProjectInformation InfoPath cannot run
>   the specified query.
>   [0x80040E14][Microsoft OLE DB Provider
>   for SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'WHERE'.

And this is the reason, for the second time,

> dataQueryConnection.Command = select
>   "EmployeeID","Accountname","ProjectName","ProjectId","ProjectRole","BillableUtilization","ClientName","BillingCode","BUHead"
>   from "TRF"."hrt_vw_ProjectInformation"
>   as "hrt_vw_ProjectInformation" WHERE
>   ProjectId = '3072507' WHERE ProjectId
>   = '3076478'

subsequent event firing biding the WHERE clause every time with the previous executed query.

How I can over come from this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Store the initial command string in a global variable in your code (in the loading event). Then in your Changed function append to the global variable instead of to the previous value of the command.

```
string OrigString

public void FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)
{
   OrigString = dataQueryConnection.Command;
}

public void ProjectName_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e) 
{ 
            string projectId = e.NewValue; 
            dataQueryConnection = (AdoQueryConnection)this.DataConnections["ProjectInformation"]; 
            dataQueryConnection.Command = OrigString + string.Format(" WHERE ProjectId = '{0}'",             projectId); 
            dataQueryConnection.Execute(); 

}
```